# Is it possible to see questions in my tags with no answers?

Tags: feature-request, support, search, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

I can click on "Unanswered" and then click on "my tags" to see questions associated with my tags. But I am looking for a way to find all questions in my tags which have no answers, can someone please suggest how can I do it.

Comment: and how is your procedure not doing what you want?

Comment: It also shows questions which has some answers.

Comment: @DaveChen - Thanks can you please tell me where to append this, appreciate that, I am new on meta site.

Comment: I click on "my tags" and it goes to following URL "http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Advanced search query: `intags:mine answers:0`

[Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+answers%3A0). :)

Comment: +1 - That is a neat link :) I like the `intags:mine` clause.

Comment: +1, but I can't seem to see [your tags](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3A447356). I used `intags:447356`, there was a result, but I didn't get to see your favorite tags :(.

Comment: @TravisJ thanks, this is rather uncommon but super useful search operator.

Comment: @DaveChen you can't see my tags and I can't see yours, it's private. Only favorite questions are public.

Comment: I have wanted this for a while now but did not think that it was possible! Thank you.